# Send email with React, Redux Form, Nodemailer and Express

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, redux-form, nodemailer

I've been trying to figure out how to send an email after submitting a Redux Form. After days of searching for a proper solution, I merged some of them and this is the result.

CLIENT SIDE:

This is the component of my contact form:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

class Info extends React.Component {
    renderError({ error, touched }) {
        if (touched && error) {
            return <div>{error}</div>
        }
    }

    renderInputField = ({ input, label, meta }) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <input {...input} type="text" placeholder={label} />
                {this.renderError(meta)}
            </div>
        );
    };

    onSubmit = (formValues) => {
        this.props.onSubmit(formValues)
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting } = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            name="nome"
                            component={this.renderInputField}
                            label="Nome *"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            name="cognome"
                            component={this.renderInputField}
                            label="Cognome *"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            name="email"
                            component={this.renderInputField}
                            label="Email *"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            name="azienda"
                            component={this.renderInputField}
                            label="Azienda"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            name="citta"
                            component={this.renderInputField}
                            label="Città / CAP / Provincia"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Visualizza</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const validate = formValues => {
    const errors = {}

    if (!formValues.nome) {
        errors.nome = "Aggiungi il nome"
    }

    if (!formValues.cognome) {
        errors.cognome = "Aggiungi il cognome"
    }

    if (!formValues.email) {
        errors.email = "Aggiungi l'email"
    } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(formValues.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Email non valida'
    }

    return errors
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'companyData',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
    validate
})(Info)
```

This is the component where the contact form is used (parent) and where I use axios to send the data to my server which is running on the port 3001.
The important part is the handleFormSubmit method:

```
import React from 'react'
import Data from '../components/form/Data'
import Calculation from '../components/form/Calculation'
import Info from '../components/form/Info'
import Details from '../components/form/Details'
import axios from 'axios'

class WizardForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this)
        this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this)
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            page: 1,
        }
    }
    nextPage() {
        this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 })
    }

    previousPage() {
        this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 })
    }

    async handleFormSubmit(formValues) {
        const name = formValues.nome
        const surname = formValues.cognome
        const email = formValues.email
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/send', {
            name: name,
            surname: surname,
            email: email,
        })
        console.log(response)
    }


    render() {
        const { page } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                {page === 1 && <Data onSubmit={this.nextPage} />}
                {page === 2 && (
                    <Calculation
                        previousPage={this.previousPage}
                        nextPage={this.nextPage}
                    />
                )}
                {page === 3 && (
                    <Info
                        onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
                    />
                )}
                {page === 4 && (
                    <div>
                        <Details />
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default WizardForm
```

SERVER SIDE:

This is my app.js file which is run by using the command "node app.js":

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));


app.use(cors());


app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'ssl0.ovh.net',
        secure: true,
        port: 465,
        auth: {
            user: 'matteo.schiatti@abstract-technology.com',
            pass: 'g6vqUImUzJX_cw',
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        }
    });

    let name = req.body.name
    let surname = req.body.surname
    let email = req.body.email
    let content = `name: ${name} \n surname: ${surname} \n email: ${email} `

    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"John" <matteo.schiatti@abstract-technology.com>', // sender address
        to: 'matteo.schiatti@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'This is a test', // Subject line
        text: content, // plain text body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    });
});


app.use((request, response, next) => {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    next();
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

With all of this in place, emails are sent but I'm facing some issues:

1 - I'm not able to get the console.log(response), nothing appears in the console, the mail is sent but axios doesn't give me the response. I've tried to search something, here it says the problem is the event.preventDefault():

[Axios post doesn't receive answer (ReactJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748598/axios-post-doesnt-receive-answer-reactjs)

but the handleSubmit of the Redux Form already uses preventDefault, and I also tried by using event.preventDefault() instead of handleSubmit but nothing. 
I really need to find the way to get the response because I need to change the "page" status when I get the positive result. Any Idea?

2- The email is sent but if I don't reload the page after (I need the page to not be reloaded because I need the form's data which are stored in Redux) I get a double email, so after few minutes another identical email is sent.

It was really diffucult to find a solution because I had to merge differente guides to figure out something, hopefully I will get this working so I can create a clear step by step guide for who will want to build something similar.

Hope I put all the info

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
   async handleFormSubmit(formValues) {
        const name = formValues.nome
        const surname = formValues.cognome
        const email = formValues.email
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/send', {
            name: name,
            surname: surname,
            email: email,
        }).then((response)=> console.log(response)
    }
```

You can send a response via API in your case in express.js when status is 200, and also if status is different.
In action when you triger you can do sth like this.

```
  function = () => {
    const { saveValue } = this.props;
     this is a async action.
    saveValues().then(() => {
      console.log('Success');
    }).catch(() => {
      console.log('Error');
    });
  };
```

2.Redux form already uses preventDefault so you dont need to call it. I think sth is wrong with your redux form code